# Appstore Connect Testflight Provide Old Build even I Uploaded New One

Tags: ios, swift, testflight, app-store-connect

I keep on getting old build in Testflight even if I upload a new one. The version and build number is correct but the project build is always the old one.

Comment: How do you know? What is the outward phenomenon? Are you claiming that if you build and run a commit on your local machine, and if you then archive that very same commit and upload it to the store and download the build thru TestFlight and run that, they behave differently? If so, in what way? (If not, you have no proof of your statement in the first place. The only valid test is using one and the same commit.)

Comment: I simply added label on my new build. And its not showing on what I get on Testflight. Did many times with different workarounds I found on Stackoverflow but same issue persists.

Comment: I'm sorry, the phrase "I simply added label on my new build" is not helpful. You must do exactly what I said. Here are step by step instructions. * Make a change in your app, including upping the build number. * Commit. * Clean the build folder. * Build and run locally on a device; test as desired. * Archive and upload to the app store, and download thru TestFlight on the same device, and run. Now, are you claiming that when you do that you see two different behaviors?

Comment: Yes Matt, I did exactly those stuff you said. And yes, I see two different behaviors/builds. Seems like what Im getting in Testflight is the old version.

Comment: Well that should be impossible. You should contact Apple. There is nothing Stack Overflow can do for you.

Comment: There were previous issues like this posted here in Stack Overflow, but the thing is the accepted answers or workarounds dont work for me.

Comment: In that case your question would be a duplicate in any case.

Comment: Those were like last 2014 or 2015 questions, answers are not applicable to what Im experiencing. So asking a new one seems a better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem, it’s the versioning of the build. Appstore doesnt recognize that 0.0.2 is newer that 0.0.1. It should be of two digits. When I tried 0.0.30 it solved the issue that it must email the testers that new build is available, but upon installing still old build is provided. I opted to go for 0.1.00 as our base version, it worked. Dont know why appstore behave like this.